# Probability of three players throwing a ball

Tags: probability

I have a question about a probability problem.
Three basketball players A, B and C independently shoot a ball one by one with probabilities 3/5, 1/2 and 2/3.
a) What is the probability that there was at least one hit (or score I don't know the exact term) if we know that player A missed?
b)What is the probability that player A scored, if we know that there was exactly one score?

I tried to solve it, but I got very confused. I would be grateful if someone solved it with a short explanation about the solution, I don't need a detailed one. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a), given that player A missed you're trying to find the probability that B scored or C scored, or both. That is 1 *minus* the probability that B and C both missed. Do you know how to calculate the probability of B and C both missing?

For part (b): have you been introduced to Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: For part (a), yes I know how to calculate it, and I am familiar with the Bayes' Theorem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

### a)

$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(\text{someone scores} \mid A\text{ misses}) & = \mathbb{P}(B\text{ or }C\text{ scores}) \\ & = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{Both }B\text{ and }C\text{ miss}) \\ & = 1 - \mathbb{P}( B\text{ misses}) \cdot P( C\text{ misses}) \\ & = 1 - (\frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 3) \\ & = \frac 5 6\end{align}$

Using the assumption of independence

### b)

$\begin{align} \mathbb{P}&(A\text{ scored}\mid\text{exactly one score}) \\ & =\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A\text{ scores}, B\text{ misses}, C\text{ misses}) }{ \left({\small (\mathbb{P}(A\text{ scores}, B\text{ misses}, C\text{ misses}) + \mathbb{P}(A\text{ misses}, B\text{ scores}, C\text{ misses}) + \mathbb{P}(A\text{ misses}, B\text{ misses}, C\text{ scores})}\right)} \\ &  = \dfrac{(\frac 3 5 \cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac 1 3) }{ ((\frac 3 5 \cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot  \frac 1 3) + (\frac 2 5 \cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac 1 3) + (\frac 2 5 \cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 2 3))} \\ & = \frac 1 3\end{align}$

with again the assumption of independence to facilitate the computation.

Apologies for the ugliness of the solution. AFAIK, using latex with the events written informally requires me to fiddle with the spacing manually.

Comment: I've MathJaxed the equations for you, if that's okay.

Comment: I think part of the denominator in the first fraction in part b got taken outside the fraction, however.

Comment: No, it's just folding over onto the next line because it's so long.